# C++ Comparison of a string and a char

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to compare a string and a char like below :

```
char filter = "    " // <<== this is a tab space, so I am assuming its one char
if ( line[counter] == filter[0]){

}
```

note that line is a normal string defined like : `string line;`. now for some reason the statement is never true even though there are no syntax errors.

**UPDATE**

inside line is : 
`string line = "1  90  74  84  48  76  76  80  85";`

**2nd UPDATE**

here is the complete function I wrote :

```
void getResults(string line){

    int tmpSize = line.length();
    int counter = 0;
    int tmpCounter = 0;

    while(counter != MAX_No_Of_Grades){

        if(line[counter] == '\t\t'){
            counter++;
        }else{
            cout << tmpCounter << ". this is : " << line[tmpCounter] << "a" << endl;
            tempGrade[counter] += line[tmpCounter];
        }
        tmpCounter++;
    }


}
```

the function is technically suppose to break the string `line` into an array by "tabspace". but right now `counter` does not change and therefore its an endless loop!

Comment: yes it does compile, and I have an else statement attached to it, and it goes straight to that line

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi You might wanna show what's inside line? Also since this is C++ why not use std::string in both places?

Comment: never seen a char declared like that in c++ before. And a missing ; to boot

Comment: @danca sorry I am working on my PC which is slow and posting this question on mac, so I had to type the code above and missed the `;`.
@FailedDev I have updated the question to show whats inside the string `line`

Comment: Did you know that: To put tab in a string, you should write `\t`? Or that the character _tab_ is `'\t'`?

Comment: @Shahbaz no unfortunately I just found out :) through the answers posted here. but for some reason I still cant get the if statement to return true eventhough I know it has to be!!!!

Comment: yeah i figured the missing ; was a typo. Still confused as to how this could compile. VS2010 is giving med the following error: "cannot convert from 'const char[2]' to 'char' which I would expect it to do. Maybe the doublequotes typo too?

Comment: @danca no the doublequotes is not a type! it compiled file for me, but note that I used the "tab" button and not spaces in the `filter` var.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what code you are actually running, because the `char filter = "   "` line has no terminator and that assignment is definitely illegal.  You cannot assign the string literal (a `char` array) to a single `char` variable.

If you want to determine whether the nth character of a string is a tabulation, the following code would probably be what you are looking for:

```
if (line[counter] == '\t') {
  // match...
}
```

---

As for updates.  If typed as `string line = "1 90 74 84 48 76 76 80 85";` in your program, there are no tabulations in this string.  There are only spaces.  Moreover, `'\t\t'` is a pair of tables.  Put a single `\t` in there for a single tab.

Here is a slightly modified version of your sample function:

```
void getResults(string line)
{
    int tmpSize = line.length();
    int counter = 0;
    int tmpCounter = 0;
    while((tmpCounter < tmpSize) && (counter != MAX_No_Of_Grades))
    {
        if(line[counter] == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            cout << tmpCounter << ". this is : " << line[tmpCounter] << "a" << endl;
            tempGrade[counter] += line[tmpCounter];
        }
        tmpCounter++;
    }
}
```

This version has an extra check in the while loop to stop consuming characters after the end of `line` is reached.  It also uses a space character since your test input does not use tabulations.

---

If this is not homework and you can use all the standard library facilities you want, I would suggest looking into more advanced input strategies.  Here is a simplified version of your function to extract every single number in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
void getResults ( const std::string& line )
{
    std::istringstream input(line);
    for (int grade=0; input >> grade;) {
        // process grade.
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the global variable and handle any number of grades, you can use a `std::vector<>` to automatically increase the "array" size as you get more and more grades.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> getResults ( const std::string& line )
{
    std::istringstream input(line);
    std::vector<int> grades;
    for (int grade=0; input >> grade;) {
        grades.push_back(grade);
    }
    return grades;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char filter = "    " // <<== this is a tab space, so I am assuming its one char
```

What you are assuming is wrong. A tab space `char` is `'\t'`.

What you  have there instead is multiple space characters.

**Edit:**

Also this : `char filter = "    "` is wrong

This `const char * filter = "    ";` //is more like it...

But this : `char = '\t';` is maybe what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Lets go over you code by parts to make things clear.

```
char filter = "    " // <<== this is a tab space, so I am assuming its one char
```

Your first statement creates a variable of type char. The type char in c++ take a value, like any other variable. The only difference is that if you try to use it with a statement, like cout, it will be interpreted as a character by it's ASCII value. What you did compiles and works, but the char you declared has the value that c++ gives for the string "    ". The value for the horizontal tab (TAB) in ASCII is 9.

So, for declaring a char of datatype char with the value for a TAB:

```
char filter = 9;
```

But you don't have to keep remembering all those values. The same way C++ will give a value for the string "    ", it will give a value for a character. If you want to get the value for characters, you have to use ''. A confusion that some make is to assume that tab is actually a group of spaces. Tabs are interpreted, by a text editor, as a group of spaces. But it is in fact a single character. In C++, the character for the tab is \t. If you actually put this inside a string and call cout, you will have a tab. The reason why \t is a single character and not two characters is because the compiler gives "special" interpretations for the immediate character after a backslash inside '' or "".

So the following will give the value of 9 to a variable of datatype char:

```
char filter = '\t';
```

Now for your if statement:

```
if ( line[counter] == filter[0])
```

Your if statement is comparing the character with index "counter" in the string line. This is possible because a string is an array of characters (It is actually a class, but don't worry about it for now). But filter is not an array, it is a single character. So it wont have an index (E.g. [0]). All you need is the variable you created. This confusion usually happens because the concept of string is often introduced without explaining that a string is not a datatype (That's why is not blue, and that's why you have to include a library).

So, just removing the index you will have:

```
if (line[counter] == filter)
```

You could, of course, just compare it to a tab directly

```
if (line[counter] == 9);
```

or

```
if (line[counter] == '\t');
```

Hope this gives you a better understanding of what is actually happening.